# EF Poco from DB crashes when using composite FKs

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Here is how my DB relations looks like

[image]

[image]

if I generate POCO classes using existing DB. VS 2015 will generate classes below,

**Entity.cs**

```
[Table("Entity")]
public partial class Entity
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Entity()
    {          
        EntityOnlineInformation = new HashSet<EntityOnlineInformation>();
    }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int EntityTypeId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int EntityId { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<EntityOnlineInformation> EntityOnlineInformation { get; set; }
}
```

**EntityOnlineInformation.cs**

```
 [Table("EntityOnlineInformation")]
    public partial class EntityOnlineInformation
    {
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 0)]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int EntityId { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 1)]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int EntitytypeId { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 2)]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int LanguageId { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 3)]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int StoreId { get; set; }

public virtual Entity Entity { get; set; }
}
```

**DBCOntext**

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
  modelBuilder.Entity<Entity>()
                .HasMany(e => e.EntityOnlineInformation)
                .WithRequired(e => e.Entity)
                .HasForeignKey(e => new { e.EntitytypeId, e.EntityId })
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

         }
```

Using this code, I am getting an exception when I do a simple select linq query, it complains with exception message below.

```
(473,10) : error 3015: Problem in mapping fragments starting at
 lines 473, 498: Foreign key constraint 'Entity_EntityOnlineInformation'
 from table EntityOnlineInformation (EntityId, EntitytypeId) to table Entity
 (EntityTypeId, EntityId):: Insufficient mapping: Foreign key must be mapped to some
 AssociationSet or EntitySets participating in a foreign key association on the conceptual side.
```

I didnt make any single change on created poco classes and dbcontext. I thought maybe my database relations are wrong but testing using edmx instead of POCO, everything works fine. what is the problem here and how can I test it? 
If I have to extend OnModelCreating method please advise how can I extend it in a partial class using metadata.

EDIT: I could have workaround by removing virtual properties in both classes and fluent syntax in OnModelCreate method. It looks like relationships are not working between objects.

thanks

Comment: This doesn't have much to do with an answer for you, but it looks like you're missing a property in your post. `EntityKeyword = new HashSet<EntityKeyword>();`, missing `EntityKeyword`

Comment: @stevenackley sorry, it is there, I just didnt add the entire class as there are many attributes. I only added related part. I edited my question now.